# Using Amazon S3 as a File System for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

I am deciding to use MongoDB as a Document management DB in my application. Initially I was thinking to use S3 as a data store but it seems mongoDB uses local file system to store data. Can I use S3 as data store in MongoDB.
thanx

Comment: But what if MongoDB is installed on EC2?

Comment: Still would be bad, S3 is not an EBS block device

Answer (score 11):

Provisioned IOPS in AWS is ideal for MongoDB.

[This link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) has notes about running MongoDB on AWS and is rather useful.